# Can't get bootstrap grid to work with shopify buy buttons

Tags: bootstrap-4

So, I'm trying to get a group of 4 shopify buy buttons to display side by side on a Bootstrap grid system. The problem is, they don't get side by side. Here is what the code looks like:

```
<div id="produtos" class="offset">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row py-1">

        <div class="col-sm-4" id='product-component-xxx'></div> //first button
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (Whatever the script is supposed to do in here)
        </script>

           -> (Other buttons just like those)

        <div class="col-sm-4" id='product-component-xxx'></div> //fourth button
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (Whatever the script is supposed to do in here)
        </script>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, putting a style="display: inline-flex;" tag here  does make them side by side, but it's not necessarily using the bootstrap grid system, what causes display problems when using smaller resolutions, like on mobile, where the buttos just go offscreen.

(Btw that's just how shopify handles the buy buttons, on a div with a script inside)

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically I made a very simple mistake while testing this out. 
Using the class tag on the buy button div DOES work, the main problem was with the id='product-component-xxx' part.

I was testing with 4 products, but all them had the same id, which obviously led the bootstrap to not understand what to do. Sometimes it's those little distractions that costs us hours of work, I figured it out by inspecting the page and noticing that the products were blocking together in one column, and then 3 more columns were blank beside them.

Hope this helps if someone else one day makes the same mistake I did.